# How to be notified when an IIS app pool crashes, starts or stopped

Tags: c#, iis, crash, monitor

I want to write a service which monitors IIS and sends an email with relevant info about the server when an app pool is stopped, started or crashes.

I cant seem to find any event that i can subscribe to which will notify me of this.

I found the NotifyServiceStatusChange() but this only works for windows services. Useful for me, but i also need IIS monitoring.

How can i monitor IIS from a C# application?

Comment: What about pooling? using the `ServerManager` class, crashes you can use `Pooling` on the `EventViewer`

Comment: @omriman12 Can you possibly elaborate? I cant find anyting in the ServerManager class called Pooling. What is Pooling?

Comment: Related? https://serverfault.com/questions/309503/iis7-email-alert-when-an-application-pool-stops

Comment: for example `https://johnlnelson.com/2014/06/15/the-microsoft-web-administration-namespace/`

Comment: `Pooling` simply means that you run a thread every `x` minutes/seconds and check whatever you need

Comment: @omriman12 Ok thanks. I believe you mean Polling not Pooling.

Comment: Maybe you can read the log of iis, in the option Loggin. By default this option is set in the path inetput\logs

Comment: this project from Codeproject may be helpful. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99634/Use-C-to-manage-IIS

Answer (score 0):

You're able to see all events about IIS in Windows Event viewer.
To open it directly open RUN window (Press Windows key + R) and write ***eventvwr***. Event viewer window will open and go to **administrative** section in left panel.

This is where important windows events logged.
Continue your way with this Microsoft documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx